# Can someone tell me how to purge android fastboot and adb, and install the latest version?

Tags: adb, reinstall

To start with I dont even know if I am using the latest fastboot and adb. For instance...adb version is Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31.

Now the reason why **I wanna purge and reinstall adb and fasboot** (using the latest one) is because it gives me this error message, error:closed...when I want to do things with my phone. My phone got softbricked thanks to a nightly ROM and it wont even let me enter the recovery mode which makes it hardcore to flash the faulty room. So, I need to work this out using my PC and Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 0):

To remove completely a package :

```
sudo apt-get purge [package-name]
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

After doing this you can again go for a fresh installation of any package.

[Link I found to install adb and fastboot on windows/linux/mac](http://dottech.org/21534/how-to-install-adb-and-fastboot-on-your-windows-computer-for-use-with-your-android-phone/)

Answer (score 0):

Install adb package.
Please follow the instructions below to install adb package:

2. Uninstall / Remove adb package.
   Please follow the steps below to uninstall adb package:

> ```
> sudo apt remove adb
> sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove
> ```

https://linux-packages.com/ubuntu-focal-fossa/package/adb